# Set TCP Terminator in Python? (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, matlab, tcp

I'm attempting to communicate with an external device over TCP with Python 3.10. I originally wrote some scripts in Matlab, which has a convenient `tcpclient` class which is really straightforward to use, and I'm attempting to replicate the same thing with Python's `socket` library.

I wrote a single Matlab function, `Send`, which simply sends a single message and waits to recieve a single message to a desired IP address and port supplied as the function's arguments. It returns the subsequent reply;

```
function [reply] = Send(ip, port, terminator, msg, replyLen)
    t = tcpclient(ip, port);
    configureTerminator(t, terminator, terminator);
    
    write(t, msg);

    if (replyLen > 0)
        reply = read(t, replyLen, "char");
    end
    
    clear t
end
```

The Matlab function above works well for my intended purposes of communcating with my external device via an ethernet cable. I want to replicate the function above in Python. So far, I got the following:

```
import socket

def Send(ip, port, terminator, msg, replyLen):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    s.connect((ip, port))
    s.send(msg)
    reply = s.recv(replyLen)
    s.close()

    return reply
```

However, I'm not finding a Python equivalent of Matlab's `configureTerminator` function.

What is the proper way to set a TCP terminator in Python's `socket` library?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `socket` is a low-level library. There is no equivalent.  TCP operates by streaming bytes and has no messages.